# Table header is being deleted when deleting row from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-select2

When I am deleting row from my table, also the table header is being deleted, how I can fix this?

```
$('#clubs tbody').on('click', '.deleteBtn', function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();  
});
```

Button tag

```html
<td>
  <button class="mb-1 btn bg-danger fas fa-trash-alt deleteBtn" 
                     title=@DbResHtml.T("Delete", "Resources")></button>
</td>
```

My button have a class of `.delete` so when I click it, my row is deleted together with my `table header`.

My table have and `id` of `clubs` while `table body` have and id of `clubsTBody`.

Table

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped my-4 " id="clubs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>@DbResHtml.T("#", "Resources")</th>
        <th>@DbResHtml.T("Клуб", "Resources")</th>
        <th>@DbResHtml.T("Лига", "Resources")</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="clubsTBody">
@foreach (var club in Model.Player.PlayerClubs)
  {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => count)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => club.Club.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => club.Club.League.LeagueType)</td>
        <td>
          <button class="mb-1 btn bg-danger fas fa-trash-alt deleteBtn"
                             title=@DbResHtml.T("Delete", "Resources")></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
  count++;
  }
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also I am adding dynamically rows into my table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select2-3').change(function() {
    var cc  = $('#select2-3').val();
    var ids = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < cc.length;i++) {
      ids.push(cc[i]);
    }
    $.ajax({
      type    : "POST",
      url     : "@Url.Action("GetClubsById","Player")",
      data    : {"ids": ids},
      success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#clubs tr').remove();
        var counter = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          $("#clubsTBody").append("<tr><td>" + counter + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + data[i].league.leagueType + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + '<button  class="mb-1 btn bg-danger fas fa-trash-alt deleteBtn"  title=@DbResHtml.T("Delete", "Resources")></button>' + "</td>" 
            + "</tr >");
          counter++;
        }
      },
      error: function(req, status, error) {
          console.log(msg);
      }
    });
    
    $('.deleteBtn').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();

      var value = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(1)').text();
      $(`#select2-3 option:selected:contains("${value}")`).prop("selected", false).parent().trigger("change");
    });
  })
    
// /.../

})
```

The problem is here, when I am removing selected item from select list, without this code, everything is working perfectly but selected items doesn't get deselected.

```
$(`#select2-3 option:selected:contains("${value}")`)
  .prop("selected", false)
  .parent()
  .trigger("change");
```

Comment: Can we see your table?

Comment: I see the problem, I will edit my post again

Comment: Answer is: $('#clubs tr').not("first").remove();    You need to write this in Ajax response Instead of $('#clubs tr').remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select2-3').change(function() {
            var cc = $('#select2-3').val();
            var ids = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < cc.length;i++){
                ids.push(cc[i]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetClubsById","Player")",
                data: {"ids": ids},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#clubsTBody tr').remove();
                    var counter = 1;
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#clubsTBody").append("<tr><td>" + counter + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + data[i].name + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + data[i].league.leagueType + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + '<button  class="mb-1 btn bg-danger fas fa-trash-alt deleteBtn"  title=@DbResHtml.T("Delete", "Resources")></button>' + "</td>" 
                    + "</tr >");
                        counter++;
                    }
                },
                error: function(req, status, error) {
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });

          $('.deleteBtn').on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();

            var value = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(1)').text();
            $(`#select2-3 option:selected:contains("${value}")`).prop("selected", false).parent().trigger("change");
        });
        });
```

You nee to write this: **$('#clubsTBody tr').remove();** instead of **$('#clubs tr').remove();**
You are removing all the TR in Ajax Response instead of Only Body TRs

Comment: See edited post, and pay attention to ```$(`#select2-3 option:selected:contains("${value}")`).prop("selected", false).parent().trigger("change");
``` this line of code

Comment: Yes, That what I am saying, You have ajax call on $('#select2-3').change(function() {. So If you delete it Trigger your Ajax call and There is code in Ajax that removed your all TR from table and append new.  in that Ajax response you need to remove only "tbody" TRs. Please check my code

Comment: nice job @KHIMAJIVALUKIYA don't know why you need po post the hole code but still nice job

Comment: Great job, works now, thanks!